# Class 'model' has no instance method '[ ]'

Tags: flutter

i'm having trouble in my flutter project

I'm using TypeAheadField like this:

```
  TypeAheadField(
    textFieldConfiguration: TextFieldConfiguration(
        autofocus: true,
        style: DefaultTextStyle.of(context)
            .style
            .copyWith(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
        decoration:
            InputDecoration(border: OutlineInputBorder())),
    suggestionsCallback: (pattern) async {
      List<LedgerMaster> _ledgerMasterList =
          await model.getFilterdPartyLedgerMaster(pattern);
      String length = _ledgerMasterList.length.toString();
      print('The Search yield $length  in the view');
      return _ledgerMasterList;
      // return await BackendService.getSuggestions(pattern);
    },
    itemBuilder: (context, suggestion) {
      print(suggestion.toString());
      return ListTile(
        leading: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart),
        title: Text(suggestion['name']),
        // subtitle: Text('\$${suggestion['price']}'),
      );
    },
    onSuggestionSelected: (suggestion) {
      Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) =>
              DashBoard()));
    },
  ),
```

LedgerMaster is my model and i inserted up to about 50 data in the database, and

I'm having error like this:

```
I/flutter ( 5298): The Search yield 50  in the view
I/flutter ( 5298): Instance of 'LedgerMaster'

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building _SuggestionsList<LedgerMaster>(dirty, dependencies: [_EffectiveTickerMode], state: _SuggestionsListState<LedgerMaster>#97ec5(ticker active)):

Class 'LedgerMaster' has no instance method '[]'.
Receiver: Instance of 'LedgerMaster'
Tried calling: []("name")
```

Comment: Kindly show the code of the model `LedgerMaster ` please

Comment: [link](https://github.com/tluanga/account_manager/blob/master/lib/business_logic/models/ledgermaster.models.dart)

Comment: You should use suggestion.name instead of suggestion['name']

Answer (score 0):

You pass array to builder but you as map
Instead suggestion['name'] call field of your class LedgerMaster

Comment: can u please show me how do i fix, im kinda new to flutter